# Single sign on from office 365 to Asp.Net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013, forms-authentication, office365

We have an Office 365 portal and an Asp.Net web application for another purpose. 
Web Application is using Forms Authentication using SQL Server database.
On Office 365 portal, we want to provide a link which will redirect to Asp.NET web application,
If the user is coming from Office 365 portal then the Asp.NET Web Application should not ask user credential. 
How can we achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the access token provided by o365, if it a valid token, you can by pass the authentication in your asp.net web app.

The application has to use (ADAL) AD authentication library to check for the access token. here is a link for samples how to do this in asp.net:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/starter-projects-and-code-samples#bk_web

Hope this helps.